# I am getting this, Error: That port is already in use. for Django. It's asking me for a password, but I don't remember it

Tags: django

I am trying to run my server, but I am getting this, Error: That port is already in use. I looked up on stackoeverflow and found that I should use [image]sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9, but it's asking me for a password which I don't know.
What should I do? How do I reset my password? Is there another way to kill the current port.
Thanks!

Comment: The same thing happens on my localhost, I have to use another port (e.g. 8080 )for my django localhost

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like

```py
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:<empty_port>
```